# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' from re.compile

Tags: python, python-re, python-3.11

Whenever I try to run this script I get this error. I have turned some things into string as reading online I found it is something to do with lists.

Here is the code:

```
from pytube import YouTube
import os

print('commands: quit, download')
interface = ''
while interface != 'quit':
    interface = str(input('> '))
    if interface.lower() == 'download':
        try:
            url = input('Url of the youtube video: ')
            yt = YouTube(url)
            stream = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
            vid_title = print('Youtube video title: ' , yt.title)
            save_path = str(input("Video saved path: "))
            stream.download(save_path)
            print('Video downloaded successfully')
        except Exception as e:
            print('An error occurred during download:', str(e))
        
    elif interface.lower() == 'quit':
        print('Application terminating')
        break
    else:
        print('Please input valid commands')
```

Here is the full traceback I got from running the code:

```
Url of the youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nJTTDjxzcaM
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python Scripts\Youtube downloader.py", line 12, in <module>
    stream = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
             ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 296, in streams
    return StreamQuery(self.fmt_streams)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 181, in fmt_streams
    extract.apply_signature(stream_manifest, self.vid_info, self.js)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 409, in apply_signature
    cipher = Cipher(js=js)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.throttling_plan = get_throttling_plan(js)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 405, in get_throttling_plan
    raw_code = get_throttling_function_code(js)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 311, in get_throttling_function_code
    name = re.escape(get_throttling_function_name(js))
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pytube\cipher.py", line 277, in get_throttling_function_name
    regex = re.compile(pattern)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\re\__init__.py", line 227, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\re\__init__.py", line 277, in _compile
    return _cache[type(pattern), pattern, flags]
           ~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

The exception occurs in the `re` module and seems unrelated to any code that I've written. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: I think this is an issue in pytube, probably [this](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1704) is related.